# Why magento installation hangs on configuration phase?

Tags: magento

I am installing a fresh magento in my Windows 7 computer. I have Xampp installed. While installing magento, I had a problem at the configuration step where I had to fill database host, username, password etc. When I click continue after filling the required fields, the installation process doesn’t move forward. I am redirected to the same page.

Comment: Some errors in your logs?

Comment: I checked the Apache error log in XAMPP and here are the last three:[Mon Oct 20 16:05:34.946812 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1632:tid 256] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Oct 20 16:05:35.274831 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 1632:tid 256] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Oct 20 16:05:35.327834 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1632:tid 256] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

Which Magento version your trying to instal? Try Magneto version 1.8.1 or higher. before installing run Magento check to test whether your server meets Magento requirements. here is the link for [Checking system requirements for Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento)

Answer (score 0):

*www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name*

Invalid Security Certificate, though it sounds like the HTTP server's starting anyway, just warning of the domain name mismatch. SSL isn't needed for installation though.

Are you using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for the host name?

Magento expects dots in the host name as it expects either a Fully Qualified Domain Name or an IP address, so if you didn't put a domain name in your computer's hosts files to resolve to, you need to use an IP address.

The other thing to consider is making sure you've set up the database on MySQL and have connected to it by other means to make sure your database login credentials actually work and that you have permissions to write to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and it solve by tick this option in db configuration:

-Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step